# SSL_VPN SRV record entry?

Tags: ssl, vpn, srv-record

I am setting up a certificate for an SSL VPN on a sonicwall device the certificate is valid and appears as such when inspected but its still seen as untrusted since the VPN sign in is through an IPaddr:port and not vpn.domain.com as stated through the cert. I created an A record that reads as

```
vpn.domain.com -> 255.255.255.255
```

{redacted actual domain and IP addr for security purposes}

This was created successfully but when going to this page it pulls up the sonicwall admin management login page which is undesirable. The goal is to have the subdomain

```
vpn.domain.com
```

point to the port that the SSL VPN server is hosted. I'm pretty sure I need a SRV record to point to a specific port on the attached A record but I want to make sure I am putting the right record in place currently I have

```
_vpn._tls.domain.com. 86400 IN SRV 5 5 1234 vpn.domain.com
```

{again domain name and port have been redacted for security}

Is my thinking and record creation correct?

Comment: From what information or documentation you derive that you need a SRV record here? From a short reading of Sonicwall documentation I conclude that it is just a normal certificate authentication, i.e. if an IP address is used as target then the IP address needs to be in the SAN of the certificate.

Comment: both the CSR and the certificate broker would not accept an IP addr and required a FQDN in order to generate the cert.

Comment: Whether SRV record will do this work depends exactly on the client application capability to use it. Some have such a capability, some don't. The proper answer could only be found in your **client** software documentation. That said, I never heard of VPN that uses SRV records. Well, and that's independent from the requirement to have hostname to request a certificate. You can have a certificate for some name, then set that name *and port* in the client configuration; client *should* check the certificate against hostname configured in it, whatever port is used. Only names are checked.

Comment: Please follow this article to double check https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-certificate-installation-sonicwall-ssl-vpn.htm. Dns records have nothing to do with an ssl vpn by the way. With a SSL VPN you connect to the SonicWall SSL VPN appliance which creates a secure connection between the vpn client and the appliance and grants you access to the network segments allowed and connected to the appliance. So as long as the VPN client has the correct cert and chain and the same in the appliance it should be all good

Comment: Owh yeah for security purposes i would stay away from creating a a dns record for the vpn appliance